# How to change field value in elasticsearch from string to integer?

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch, mapping, reindex

I have some data indexed in elasticsearch, in _source I have a field to store file size:
    {"file_size":"25.2MB"}
    {"file_size":"2GB"}
    {"file_size":"800KB"}

Currently the mapping of this field is string. I want to do search with sorting by file_size. I guess I need change the mapping to integer and do re-index.

How can I calculate the size in bytes and re-index them as integer?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Also can you share what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elasticsearch does not support field reindexing, as documents in `lucene`s index is immutable. So, internally, every document need to be fetched, changed, indexed back to index and old copy should be removed. Its doesn't matter what you actually need - change mapping or change data.

So, about practical part. Straightforward way:

1. Create new index with proper mapping
2. Fetch all your documents from old index
3. Change your `file_size` field to integer according to any logic you need
4. Index documents to new index
5. Drop old index after full migration

So, application side will contain additional logic to transform data from human-readable strings to `Long` + standard ES driver functionality. To speed this process up, consider using [`scroll-scan`](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-scroll.html) for read and [`bulk api`](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html) for write. For future, I recommend using [aliases](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-aliases.html) to be able to migrate your data seamlessly.

In case, when you can't do server-side changes for some reason, you can potentially add new field with proper mapping and fire up ES-side updates with [scripted partial updates](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/partial-updates.html#_using_scripts_to_make_partial_updates) (). Or try your luck with [experimental plugin](https://github.com/yakaz/elasticsearch-action-updatebyquery/)

Answer (score 0):

why not use sort by keyword?

just add this:

```
{
    "sort": {
        "file_size.keyword": {
            "order": "asc"
        }
    }
}
```

it was only sort it by string, so if there is data 2.5GB, 1KB, 5KB, the data will be 1KB, 2.5GB, 5KB

i think you have to save it into Byte first, so you can easily sorting it if it was in the same format.